# Starting a Script while scrolling into view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, webflow

So I'm pretty new to this whole stuff and have a question about some code.
I created a Webflow website and with a Script I found I want to write out words, which works fine. However, I want to achieve this effect multiple times while scrolling on the site. At the moment all the scripts are triggered at the same time (When the page finishes loading) and I would like to have it so that when I scroll over the section my Script starts.

Here is the Script:

```
 <script>
    var typed4 = new Typed('.typed-text2', {
    strings: ['Unser Angebot'],
    typeSpeed: 75,
    backSpeed: 25,
    bindInputFocusEvents: true,
    loop: false,
    cursorChar: '',
    backDelay: 1000,
    startDelay: 1000
  });
</script>
```

Would appreciate some advice!

Comment: Do you want it to get triggered when the section comes into view on scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onscroll event. Code example is below

```
<div onscroll = "myFunction()">    
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var typed4 = new Typed('.typed-text2', {
    strings: ['Unser Angebot'],
    typeSpeed: 75,
    backSpeed: 25,
    bindInputFocusEvents: true,
    loop: false,
    cursorChar: '',
    backDelay: 1000,
    startDelay: 1000
  });
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer. So I added the code to my Project, but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to change the myFunction with something?

Comment: I really don't know, but you can use this link to help. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Comment: Ok, I am very sorry on doing half research, but what we forgot to add was like only one line. And it is the following. document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction); Put this line in the script tag, but before the function.